# How to pass web RTSP parameters to VLC

Tags: web, vlc

Hi i bought a cheap DVR RECORDER and i want pass video from web page to VLC. I have tried many times but VLC says BAD MRL.

In web page everything works fine.

```
<embed src="back.GIF" name="movie1" qtsrc="rtsp://192.168.0.22:554/user=admin&amp;password=&amp;channel=1&amp;stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100" controller="false" loop="false" scale="tofit" wmode="Transparent" autoplay="true" kioskmode="true" enablejavasript="true" href="javaScript:void(0)" target="Myself" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="black" plugin="quicktimeplugin" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried. If I understand correctly you want to open an rtsp stream with specific parameters in VLC? What happens if you simply copy the `rtsp://192.168.0.22:554/` or `rtsp://192.168.0.22:554/user=admin&amp;password=&amp;channel=1&amp;stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100` into VLC? Does your DVR recorder state a rtsp URL pattern to use for watching a stream (maybe in the manual)...

Comment: My DVR is www.genway.pl/dvr-004h-ii-vidiline-rejestrator-hybrydowy-ahd-4ch.html
In manual does not have any line about RSTP OR extrenal streamin. It own own cloud server where it sreaming. But i want get local stream, in my local network. 
http://pastebin.com/T2mMeLv2

Comment: Ok, what language is that in the manual: polish? It doesn't state an explicit RTSP address. You could intercept the stream by using wireshark and see what's going on? However I just found this post here which has an answer dealing with the exact same rtsp address components/format: http://superuser.com/questions/726942/how-do-i-find-the-video-stream-url-of-my-security-dvr-by-myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking into the answers posted at SuperUser. See the [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/746420/311059) on "[How do I find the video stream URL of my security DVR by myself?](https://superuser.com/q/726942/311059)" which refers to the exact same URL setup you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys Wireshark Helped me. 
Here is good parameter !

vlc  "rtsp://192.168.0.22:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100"